# How can I get every memory address and its value?

Tags: c#, memory

Think of Cheat Engine or any other memory editing software. I want to do something that they do. I want to get every address and read the value so I can change it to what I want it to. With my code, I have tried going through each address one by one. Because there is so many addresses, this will obviously take very long. I have then tried threading to speed up the process but the time frame is still ridiculously long.

In memory editing software such as Cheat Engine, they read memory information almost instantly. When a process is selected, the memory view updates repetitively in fast speeds compared to what I am trying. How can I scan addresses and read their values faster than the way I have tried?

```
                                           **CODE**
```

Function use

```
        Task[] threadpool = new Task[5];
        threadpool[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanforaddresses(0x30000000, "0x32000000", 1));
        threadpool[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanforaddresses(0x32000000, "0x34000000", 2));
        threadpool[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanforaddresses(0x34000000, "0x36000000", 3));
        threadpool[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanforaddresses(0x36000000, "0x38000000", 4));
        threadpool[4] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanforaddresses(0x38000000, "0x40000000", 5));
        Task.WaitAll(threadpool);
```

Scanning addresses

---

```
        public void scanforaddresses(int start, string cap, int threadid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("started " + threadid);
            IntPtr currentAddress = new IntPtr(start);
            while (true)
            {
                addressValue = GetMemoryAddress.HexToString(Class_Memory.ReadAddressAOB(HexStringToInt(currentAddress.ToString("X8")), 10));
                filtervalue = GetMemoryAddress.HexToString(Class_Memory.ReadAddressAOB(HexStringToInt(currentAddress.ToString("X8")) + 4, 6));
                if (AlphaNumeric(addressValue))
                {
                    if (addressValue.Length == 10)
                    {
                        if (addressValue.Substring(4) == filtervalue)
                        {
                            memoryvalues.Add(new List<string>() { currentAddress.ToString("X8"), addressValue });
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (HexStringToInt(currentAddress.ToString("X8")) > HexStringToInt(cap))
                {
                    break;
                }
                currentAddress = new IntPtr(currentAddress.ToInt32() + 1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End " + threadid);
        }
```

Comment: What does the `Class_Memory.ReadAddressAOB` method do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use WinAPI methods through pinvoke

```
class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        int nSize,
        out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        int nSize,
        out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory( 
        IntPtr hProcess, 
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, 
        int dwSize, 
        out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess, 
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lpBuffer, 
        int dwSize, 
        out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess, 
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        IntPtr lpBuffer, 
        int dwSize, 
        out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
}
```

a sample of usage:

```
var targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("target.exe");
IntPtr targetProcAddress = GetAddres();
byte[] data = GetData();
int bytesWriten;
int retVal = NativeMethods.WriteProcessMemory(targetProcess.Handle, targetProcAddress , data, data.Length, out bytesWriten);
```

using ReadProcessMemory is simular.